# VScode - No syntax highlighting inside {% schema %} or {% stylesheet %} tags in .liquid file

Tags: visual-studio-code, shopify, liquid

I've started a new job working on shopify templates and am having trouble getting the syntax highlighting to work in VSCode. I have installed the Liquid Languages Support and Shopify Liquid Template Snippets extensions, but on my .liquid files there is no syntax highlighting inside the `{% schema %}` or `{% stylesheet %}` tags. Is there an extension or way inside VSCode to get this to work, similar to how a regular html file would recognize `<style>` or `<script>` tags?

Including screenshots of the `{% schema %}` and `{% stylesheet %}` tags with no syntax highlighting, and other liquid tags with working syntax highlighting. The file is in HTML Liquid language mode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `schema` and `stylesheet` objects content are not liquid code. The schema is JSON syntax and `stylesheet` is CSS. That's why you don't get any highlights there.

Comment: Yes but on a typical html page, it would recognize css and json inside <style> and <script> tags and apply syntax higlighting, so I'm looking for a way to have that same functionality in a liquid file. I should have mentioned the file is in HTML Liquid language mode.

Comment: I know this is late to the party but the Liquid Languages Support is about as helpful as shit on your shoe. Install the [vscode-liquid](https://github.com/panoply/vscode-liquid) extension and you will get syntax highlighting + formatting and all the other jazz.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [VS Code Liquid extension](https://github.com/panoply/vscode-liquid) by Nikolas Savvidis.

I use Locomotive CMS which also requires mixed code types within files and [Liquid Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilding.language-liquid) can't handle it.

I installed the former and disabled the latter and haven't looked back.